# Defining decidable equality for dependent pair in Agda

Tags: equality, agda, dependent-type, existential-type

I am trying to define decidable equality on a sigma type, but getting stuck despite my goal matches what I have in the hole.

```
module SigmaEqual where

open import Function using (id)
open import Data.Nat using (ℕ) renaming (_≟_ to _≟ℕ_)
open import Data.Product using (Σ; _,_; proj₁; proj₂)
open import Relation.Nullary using (yes; no)
open import Relation.Binary using (Decidable)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_; cong; refl)

data B : ℕ → Set where
  bcons : (n : ℕ) → B n

Tuple = Σ ℕ B

_≟B_ : ∀ {n} → Decidable {A = B n} _≡_
bcons n ≟B bcons .n = yes refl

_≟_ : Decidable {A = Tuple} _≡_
(n₁ , b₁) ≟ (n₂ , b₂) with n₁ ≟ℕ n₂
(n₁ , b₁) ≟ (n₂ , b₂) | no ¬p = no λ q → ¬p (cong proj₁ q)
(n₁ , b₁) ≟ (.n₁ , b₂) | yes refl with b₁ ≟B b₂
(n₁ , b₁) ≟ (.n₁ , .b₁) | yes refl | yes refl = yes refl
(n₁ , b₁) ≟ (.n₁ , b₂) | yes refl | no ¬p = no λ q → ¬p (lemm {n₁} {b₁} {b₂} q)
  where
  lemm : {a : ℕ}{b₁ b₂ : B n₁} → (a , b₁) ≡ (a , b₂) → b₁ ≡ b₂
  lemm refl = refl
```

When I inspect the context in the hole I have the following:

```
Goal: (n₁ , b₁) ≡ (n₁ , b₂)
Have: (n₁ , b₁) ≡ (n₁ , b₂)
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
q  : (n₁ , b₁) ≡ (n₁ , b₂)
¬p : b₁ ≡ b₂ → .Data.Empty.⊥
...
```

So I imagine I should be able to refine this and place `q` in its place, but it doesn't work and if I put `q`, I get the following error.

```
x != n₁ of type ℕ when checking that the expression q has type (n₁ , b₁) ≡ (n₁ , b₂)
```

This is particularly baffling as I don't know where the `x` in question comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can figure out what's going on by adding the following lines at the top of your file:

```
{-# OPTIONS --show-implicit #-}
open import Agda.Primitive
```

Then you can see what goes wrong:

```
Goal: _≡_ {lzero} {Σ {lzero} {lzero} ℕ (λ v → B n₁)} (n₁ , b₁)
      (n₁ , b₂)
Have: _≡_ {lzero} {Σ {lzero} {lzero} ℕ B} (n₁ , b₁) (n₁ , b₂)
```

You can see in the goal you have a non-dependent sigma type but your lemma has a dependent one! So you just need to change the dependency of `B` on n₁ in your lemma to `a`:

```
lemm : {a : ℕ}{b₁ b₂ : B a} → _≡_ {A = Tuple} (a , b₁) (a , b₂) → b₁ ≡ b₂
lemm refl = refl
```

With this small change to the type of `lemma`, your proof is accepted!

Answer (score 1):

In this case (as is often the case when the goal and the have apparently match yet Agda gives the grief) the problem is due to implicit variables not matching. If you turn on `show-implicit` (either via `C-c C-x C-h` or `{-# OPTIONS --show-implicit #-}`) and then compare `Goal` and `Have`, you can spot the difference, thus unbaffling yourself. (Figuring out why there is such a difference is a separate problem.)